# How do I specify sample size with matchit() in R?

Tags: r, matching

I have a data frame with 120 experimental subjects and 147 controls. I want to get two groups of 100 matched on age, sex and BMI.

Using the MatchIt package:

```
match.it <- matchit(group ~ age + sex + bmi , data, method="nearest", ratio=1)
summary(match.it)$nn  #return sample sizes
          Control Treated
All           147     120
Matched       120     120
Unmatched      27       0
Discarded       0       0
```

You can see that it automatically returns sample sizes equal to the smallest of the original sample sizes. I would like to force it to only keep 100 controls and 100 treated samples, but I don't want to specify which ones. I've scoured the documentation, but don't see a way to specify the matched sample size (only the ratio of treated to control).

1. Is there a way to do it that I'm overlooking?
2. If not, is there a way to do it using the 'distance' metric returned by match.data()?
3. If MatchIt is not the right package for this, do you know of a better one?

Thanks

---

Update: I was able to return the matched subjects using the summary(match.it)$match.matrix and put them into a new data frame. I also included their distances and calculate the difference between distances for each pair. If I were to use this to choose 100 pairs, should I choose those with the smallest difference in distance, or the smallest average distance, or something else. I'm not familiar enough with the math to know exactly how to interpret the distance.

Edit: fixed a typo in the code

Comment: This would be easier to answer if we could see `data`. Also, should it be `summary(match.it)` not `summary(match.it.1)` ? One possibility is to extract the row names with matches from `match.it$match.matrix`, use those to subset the original data frame, then use something like `dplyr::sample_n()` to obtain 100 randomly-sampled matching rows.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that typo, neilfws. As I put in the update I pulled the matched pairs, but was thinking of using the distances to choose the most closely matched pairs. Do you think a random sampling would be better? I guess it doesn't matter too much as long as the group differences in age, sex and BMI are acceptable.

Comment: I assumed random samples based on your criteria "keep 100 controls and 100 treated samples, but I don't want to specify which ones." If you want "the 100 best matches by distance", that's a different criterion. I guess which is better depends on the next step. For example, you may want to sample and see if the results are comparable.

Comment: You might also consider an exact match on sex, since a distance based match is sort of silly for this variable.  I haven't played around with `matchit`, but I know the `Matching` package has an exact argument. Something else to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give a brief explanation of how I solved my problem, then try to come back with a more detailed explanation including some code when I have more time.

The matchit() function will return the list of matched cases by row number [["matched.matrix"]] and the match.data() function will return the match cases with the original data, plus the distance metric for each case as calculated by the nearest neighbor approach.

Now, keep in mind I don't really know how to interpret the distance metric, so I tried several different methods for picking the best 100 pairs. I made a data frame with each pair in a row and calculated the absolute difference of the distances and the average of the distances. I then tested different subsets of 100 pairs for t-tests of age, sex and BMI between treatment and control groups. The five groups were; 1. 100 randomly chosen pairs, 2. Top 100 based on average distance, 3. Bottom 100 based on average distance, 4. Top 100 based on difference of distances, and 5. Bottom 100 based on difference of distances.

In my data set, group #5 yielded the best results (least significant differences between groups for age, sex and BMI). I don't know for sure that these results would extend to other data sets, but it makes sense if closer differences mean more closely matched cases.

Sorry if my wordy explanation isn't very clear. I will try to come back and edit it later to add example code and clean it up.